# Jade not correctly rendering elements with ng-view directive

Tags: node.js, angularjs, pug

I'm writing a basic Node app and simply want to render the index page with Jade, and then let Angular do the rest on the front-end.

This is the Jade (slightly shortened to illustrate the problem):

```
doctype html
html
    include ../includes/head

    body(ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="TestAppController")

            div(ng-view)

    include ../includes/foot
```

Which compiles to the following HTML:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Example App</title>      
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/css/app.css">
    </head>

    <body ng-app="ExampleApp" ng-controller="ExampleAppController" class="ng-scope">

        <!-- ngView:  -->

        <footer class="page-footer">
            <ul class="page-footer-links">
                <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/someusername" target="_blank">Some Twitter User</a></li>
            </ul>
        </footer>

        <script src="/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Notice how `div(ng-view)` is now an HTML comment within the rendered HTML, rather than a DIV with the directive:

```
<!-- ngView:  -->
```

Changing `div(ng-view)` within the Jade to any of the following produced the same result for me:

```
ng-view

<div ng-view></div>

| <div ng-view></div>
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: already tried _div(ng-view="")_  ?

Comment: The `<!-- ngView:  -->` is most probably the placeholder created by Angular upon seing a `<div ng-view>` *and having no route to display in it*. Check your `$routeProvider` configuration.

Comment: thanks guys. @Infer-On I did try that and got the same result.
It seems I had a small error in my JS, so now it works as expected. But @NikosParaskevopoulos, I had no idea that Angular would automatically comment the `ng-view` element though, do you know if this is documented somewhere? And please add this as an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually nothing to do with Jade. As stated in a comment by @NikosParaskevopoulos, the `<!-- ngView:  -->` HTML comment is a placeholder created by Angular upon seeing a `<div ng-view>` and having no route to display in it.

Redefining my Angular routes solved the problem.